# How to fix "Error inflating class GeckoEngineView" for android

Tags: java, android, geckoview

The GeckoEngineView fails to be inflated, despite using latest dependencies.

The code is from an official documentation on [GeckoView](http://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView). All the latest dependencies and repos have been successfully resolved in the project.

The Error:

`Error inflating class mozilla.components.browser.engine.gecko.GeckoEngineView`

Upon scouring the error log:

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class mozilla.components.browser.engine.gecko.GeckoEngineView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class mozilla.components.browser.engine.gecko.GeckoEngineView
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mozilla.components.browser.engine.gecko.GeckoEngineView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.geckoengine.example-IQhwqfpsfzKO11EI9ak6kQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.geckoengine.example-IQhwqfpsfzKO11EI9ak6kQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.geckoengine.example-IQhwqfpsfzKO11EI9ak6kQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
```

*Updated XML File, Credit: @ArturoMejia*
`activity_main.xml`:

```
<org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoView
    android:id="@+id/geckoview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GeckoView view;
    GeckoSession session;
    GeckoRuntime runtime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        view = findViewById(R.id.geckoview);
        session = new GeckoSession();
        runtime = GeckoRuntime.create(this);
        session.open(runtime);
        view.setSession(session);


        //TODO: add any url
        //TODO: Use intent.putExtraString() to send a url from the main activity to this activity
        session.loadUri("http://theyouthbuzz.com/");
    }
}
```

The documentation implies that the code should load a webview without any problems. The same is not verifiable.

Notes:

Android studio version: 3.5 RC 3 [dev channel]

Comment: Did you add the dependency: `implementation "org.mozilla.components:browser-engine-gecko:{latest-version}"` ?

Comment: You have to change {latest-version} with the latest version of this library. Check on the doc of the library. It seems 9.0.0

Comment: Did my comment solve your issue?

Comment: Thanks. Just posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the component [doc](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/android-components/tree/master/components/browser/engine-gecko) to use it you have to add this dependencies in your `build.gradle`

```
implementation "org.mozilla.components:browser-engine-gecko:{latest-version}"
```

Currently the [latest version](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/android-components/releases) is 9.0.0

```
implementation "org.mozilla.components:browser-engine-gecko:9.0.0"
```

Answer (score 4):

@SowingFiber I think you have a small error, on the XML code on the example above, possible in the last edition. I think you should update it because, as it's now, it is not going to compile.

The problem is that you have two different types of references, one in the XML and another in the code. To match the reference in the code, you have to use `org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoView` in the XML.

```
<org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoView
    android:id="@+id/geckoview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Additionally you could include `geckoview` directly, without using [Mozilla Android Components](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/android-components), in case you just want to use `geckoview`.

```
implementation "org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview-${geckoviewChannel}:${geckoviewVersion}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override this onCreateView of your actvity

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(parent: View?, name: String?, context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?): View? = when (name) {
       EngineView::class.java.name -> engine.createView(context, attrs).asView()
       else -> super.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs)
}
```